# python module matplotlib not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, module

Trying to use the matplotlib module however when I try and run it I get, ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'. I've had a look online but I couldn't find any solution.

Any ideas on what I could do to fix this and if not any suggestions on similar modules.

Comment: Install python distribution like Anaconda: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have it installed.Just type this in your terminal/cmd:

```
 pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: when I used this in both IDLE and cmd it did not work... am i doing this right

Comment: Do you have python installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install matplotlib
```

if you are using python3

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```